# Schedule an event (to start HKWorkoutSession) on AppleWatch with watchOS2

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I want the AppleWatch to trigger an event after a certain amount of **time**. When this event is fired I want to start a HKWorkoutSession and monitor HeartRate, what are my options (if any)?

Could I use a NSTimer to schedule a fire date on the watch?

Should I send a WCSession message to the phone so that the phone could send an event via notification or WatchConnectivity after **time**?

The things I can assume for my users are that the phone is put away (the phone won't display the notification) and the WatchApp is the the foreground (screen potentially/most likely locked by lowered wrist).